# compiling C code under VS 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, structure

I'm trying to compile an older C code under MS VS 2010. The error occurs with struct declaration and calling.

Declaration (edit):

```
typedef struct tStr
{
int nInt;
int ***anPoint;
};
```

Usage:

```
struct tStr tStuff;
tStuff.nInt = 0;
```

Function declaration (edit: probably works now):

```
int doStuff(struct tStr *sStuff, int nStuff);
```

The compiler complains about unidentified identifiers, missing ( or ; or { and so on. They are all categorized as syntax errors. What I checked the syntax should be ok. So I am at my end...

I redid the struct declaration. Yet still the same error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

Ok, back to the old declaration. But if I try to access the struct variables as in usage, I get an error:

```
error C2065: 'tStuff' : undeclared identifier
```

So my live code is:

```
typedef struct tMatrix
{
int nRows;
int nCols;
int nVec;
int ***anMatrix;
};

int allocateMatrix(struct tMatrix *sMatrix, int nType);

struct tMatrix sMatrix1;
sMatrix1.nRows = 0;
```

The errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
error C2065: 'sMatrix1' : undeclared identifier
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thank you for all the answers, I guess I'll just rewrite it. I also get a lot more other errors about type conversion and so... To avoid a headache I'll just start fresh. Thanks again.

Comment: The snippets look ok. Could you supply a complete, yet small, example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please show a short snippet that exhibits the problem. Also note, that Visual Studio only contains a C++ compiler, as such your code will always get compiled as C++ and only those C parts are supported that are in the C89 standard.

Comment: Can we see the error message?

Comment: Efter the edit, your code does not hold together. You have dropped the typedef of `TStr` to `struct tStr`.

Comment: The `typedef` was perfectly legal C (and C++) code, no need to do away with it.

Comment: Please show the full code you're trying to compile. Otherwise, we won't get anywhere. Just copy and paste it directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into VS and got nearly the same error when `sMatrix1.nRows = 0;` is in global scope (outside of any function). Is that code actually in global scope or is it inside a function?

Comment: Do you use the `/TC` ("Compile as C code") compiler switch?

Comment: @Xeo: Visual Studio *does* come bundled with a C compiler, but you're right that it only supports the C89 standard. You have to enable it with the `/TC` switch, or by naming your file with the `.c` extension (instead of `.cpp`).

Comment: @Cody: It does? My bad then! I only ever heard of it having a C++ compiler only. :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you are missing a parameter to `typedef` (continue on for the full explanation).

The syntax for `typedef` is:

typedef *type-definition*  *identifier*;

In your example the type definition is the `struct tStr` and the identifier is missing.

If you want to create a new type definition from your structure, you would declare it something like this:

```
typedef struct tStr_ {
    int nInt;
    int ***anPoint;
} tStr;
```

Now you can refer to the new type `tStr` in your code:

```
tStr tStuff;
tStuff.nInt = 0;
```

In this example `tStr_` is the name of the struct and `tStr` is the name of the new type. You can still refer to the struct by its name as well:

```
struct tStr_ tStuff;
tStuff.nInt = 0;
```

Edit: Perhaps we need a more complete example of what you are trying to accomplish. The following code sample compiles without errors and produces the expected result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tMatrix_ {
    int nRows;
    int nCols;
    int nVec;
    int ***anMatrix;
} tMatrix;

int allocateMatrix(tMatrix *sMatrix, int nType) 
{
    sMatrix->nRows = 10;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{       
    tMatrix sMatrix1;
    allocateMatrix(&sMatrix1, 0);
    printf("%d\n", sMatrix1.nRows);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Still the same error as before. If I try to declare it without the struct through the alias i get: error C2275: 'tMatrix' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: I get IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed

Comment: @drjackill: Note that you should not always trust IntelliSense. It's often faulty if some code changes invalidated the database and IntelliSense hasn't gotten around to reparsing the code yet. The only thing you can trust is to actually compile the code and look at the errors. :)

Comment: @drjackill: I must admit I'm exclusively an UNIX user so I don't know what IntelliSense is. If your C compiler can't compile the sample program I provided (which is strictly ANSI C) then you have bigger problems than I'm able to solve. Cheers and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you typedef a struct in C, the usage should be:

```
struct TStr tStuff;
```

Comment: The question was fixed, and it was edited because of an answer. It was typedef'd before.

Comment: Your usage of typedef is wrong. It's not declaring any types.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the /Tc command line argument in the project file? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx